# change UILabel's text color for total project

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, textcolor

i want to change all the UILabel's text color for total app how can i do this .is there any simple way to change label color.

i tried this ,but i want to change write this code in every class

```
for( UIView *view in [testScroll subviews])
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            [(UILabel *)view setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        }
        else if([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])

    }
```

Do anyone have simple method .

Comment: Are you targeting iOS 5+ ?

Answer (score 12):

Well if you're targeting iOS 5+ you could do that really easy (inside you appdelegate):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...

    //This color will affect every label in your app
    [[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 

    //...

    return YES;
}
```

This works because `UILabel` conforms to `UIAppearance` protocol, so you could customize any class that conforms to the protocol like this. For more information on this [here is a nice tutorial to get you started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) and [here is Apple's docs on the protocol](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)

Comment: Blue is prettier: `[[UILabel appearance] setColor:[UIColor blueColor]];` ^^

Comment: Changed my mind: `[[UILabel appearance] setColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];`

Comment: +1 simple and affective. Not sure why you would do it any other way.

Comment: It seems there could be some issues using this method according to discussion in this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839044/how-do-i-apply-uiappearance-proxy-properties-to-uilabel. I haven't tried it personally.

Comment: To my knowledge UIlabel and UIButton conforms to the UIAppearanceContainer protocol but don't actually have any property marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR

Comment: @Alladinian In fact in the Ray wenderlich article you have posted, its mentioned you should not customize UILabel using appearance proxy.

Comment: @Filip XD, @Adi I wouldn't post the answer without testing it first. Maybe was a bug that is fixed now but `setTextColor:` **does** work for me.

Comment: [[UILabel appearance] setColor:[UIColor blueColor]];works for me i want to make headings with separate color and bold how to do that?

Comment: @user2197875 is `setTextColor:` not `setColor:`

Comment: @Adi [Ray's updated tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6) includes `UILabel` and [so does this one](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/24/using-appearance-proxy-to-style-apps.html). Though it's pretty easy to give it a spin and see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
@interface CustomLabel : UILabel
 @end

 @implementation CustomLabel

 - (id)init{
  if ([super init]){
      self.textColor = // Putt here the color you want.
  }

   return self;
 }
```

and now jus use your CustomLabel.

Comment: can i change in appdelegate file

Comment: Why would you do this when you can just use [[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];? Which will change the text color of all UILabels. Please could you explain and give a reason to do it your way over using appearance?

Comment: @Popeye because doing with UIAppareance is not flexible,imagine if one day he wants that one label will we redColor and all the others blue color :)

Comment: That's fine you can just change it for that particular label, and that isn't what they have asked. Not going to downvote as it is still correct but I am not going to upvote ever as I wouldn't do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of the UILabel. You can override the init functions where you can set the text Color you want. Use that subclass throughout your project.

Comment: Why would you do this when you can just use `[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];`? Which will change the text color of all UILabels. Please could you explain and give a reason to do it your way over using `appearance`?

Comment: @Popeye It seems there are some issues with using UIAppearence proxy on UILabel. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11839198/1029360

Comment: @Popeye i couldn't get redcolor labels using ur statement

Comment: @Adi I can't say I have ever experienced any of these issues. I use it all the time and it works fine for me. I'm going to make the point that I'm not going to downvote as it is still correct, but I am not going to upvote ever as I wouldn't do it this way I would do it `Alladinians` way.

Comment: @Popeye Yes, using appearance proxy for UILabel would had been the best method if not for this uncertainty. Hopefully it will be stable in ios7.

Comment: @Adi Sorry I'm not sure I see your issue with `UIAppearence` I have never had any issues with it, it has always worked the way I want it to work.