# How to set text color for all subviews?

Tags: ios, uiview, uicolor

For example, I create a `UIView` which has some `UILabel` and `UIButton` subviews inside. All of the subviews has different text colors.

Is there an easy way to set text color for all subviews and cancel it? It should works like mask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `UIButton`, if they are the default type (.RoundedRectType), it's as simple as setting the `tintColor` property to the one you want **on their superview**. For `UILabel` unfortunately that's not enough, but you might subclass `UILabel` and override the `-tintColorDidChange` method like so:

```
// In MyLabelSubclass.m
- (void)tintColorDidChange {
    self.textColor = self.tintColor;
}

// Swift version
override func tintColorDidChange {
    textColor = tintColor
}
```

For more information about why `UILabel` doesn't automatically update it's `textColor` when the `tintColor` changes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19262685/737105) is a great explanation of what's going on and the reasoning behind this technical choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a loop on subviews of your view

```
for (UIView *view in yourView.subviews)
{
   if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] )
    {
      UILabel *label = (UILabel*)view;
      label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
  //Similarly you can check and change for UIButton , All UI Elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using either of following ways:

1. By setting `UIAppearance` in `UILabel` and `UIButton` in `AppDelegate` class, [check link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16937315/3633534). OR
2. By creating subclass of `UILabel` and `UIButton`.

I prefer the first one:

```
- (BOOL)application : (UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //This color will affect every label in your app
     [[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 
    [[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you get all the subviews then you cast them based on their type
after that you change their color

```
let subviews = view.subviews
        
        for v in subviews{
            if v is UILabel {
                let currentLabel = v as! UILabel
                currentLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            } else if v is UIButton {
                let currentButton = v as! UIButton
                currentButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for:.normal)
            }
        }
```

here I have changed the color for both UIbuttons and UILabels to white