# UIAppearance has no effect on Label text color

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios9, uiappearance

I am setting the text color of all the labels in my app using `UIAppearance`. Yet the text color does not change.

Here is a sample of how i create the label

```
//show the loading message
MessageLabel *messageLabel = [[MessageLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
messageLabel.text = @"\n\nLoading ...\n\n";
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[messageLabel sizeToFit];
self.tableview.backgroundView = messageLabel;
```

Here is how i set the text color

```
[[MessageLabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

One note is that all these `MessageLabel` are BackgroundViews of UITableView

Comment: where r u doing the setTExtColor ?

Comment: i have a button `Change Text Color`. I do it there. Its just this label that does not update. Other button and labels that i am doing the same update correctly. The only difference is that the other labels and such i have created in IB while this is the only one being created in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839044/how-do-i-apply-uiappearance-proxy-properties-to-uilabel), UIAppearance kind of doesn't really seem work with UILabel...

Since you're subclassing from UILabel, maybe it would make sense to set `textcolor` property `initWithFrame:` method on in your **MessageLabel** class?

Or another option, since you say these **MessageLabel** instances are used for UITableViewCell's background, maybe it would make sense to leave label's background clear and change background of cell itself, for example in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method in tableView's delegate?

Answer (score 2):

As arrteme mentioned, UILabel's textColor doesn't work with UIAppearance. I got around this by adding a UIAppearance compatible property that just wraps textColor. In Swift this would look something like

```
class MessageLabel: UILabel {

    @objc dynamic var configurableTextColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return textColor
        }
        set {
            textColor = newValue
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and then to configure the appearance:

```
MessageLabel.appearance().configurableTextColor = .black
```

Comment: This is the only solution I've found that worked for me. I made it an extension instead of a subclass, though, and that still works.

`extension UILabel {
    
    @objc dynamic var configurableTextColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return textColor
        }
        set {
            textColor = newValue
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

**From the Documentation:**

> iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it
>   doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To
>   change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove
>   the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back.

Comment: i am certainly doing that. Other components are updating correctly with values i set via `UIAppearance` only this has issues

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiated a UILabel in code, you must manually set `textColor` property after you set the appearance.

```
messageLabel.textColor = [[UILabel appearance] textColor];
```