# How to default UILabel Font and Size using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uiappearance

I find `UISegmentedControl` change font and size like this :

`UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(myFontAttribute as [NSObject : AnyObject] , forState: .Normal)`

but UILabel have no this method

I want to do like

`UILabel.appearance().setAttributed(myFontAttribute)`

I don't want to change UILabel font in StoryBoard

I want to using program to do this (because my app is done, but only font should change to bigger and other font)

What should I do ?

Comment: you just want to change font and size or attributed string ?

Comment: attributed string is better

Comment: `UIAppearance` only allows you to set properties that are flagged with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` in the Objective-C header file.  Since `UILabel` has no such properties, it cannot be styled with `UIAppearance`  See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839044/how-do-i-apply-uiappearance-proxy-properties-to-uilabel), which is essentially the exactly the same question, but using Objective-C

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First you need to add extension to UILabel  :

```
extension UILabel{
    var defaultFont: UIFont? {
        get { return self.font }
        set { self.font = newValue }
    }
}
```

Second use appearance to set it:

```
    UILabel.appearance().defaultFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this has been invaluable. Here's how I applied it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138367/how-do-i-rewrite-a-uilabel-after-it-is-added-to-a-subview

Answer (score 12):

You can change the label font programmatically like this

```
label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 14)
```

Change font size only with bold

```
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18)
```

Change font size only

```
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(14)
```

Comment: this idea not good for me, because it need IBOutlet ... I don't want to using IBOutlet. Because I have a lot UILable in my app.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change the size of font, used below lines of code :

**for Swift 3 :**

```
label.font = label.font.withSize(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code in swift

```
myLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myLabel.text!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "YourFont", size: 12), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
```