# my initial problems with UIScrollView now appear to be related to autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uilabel

For my first challenge using `UIScrollView` I modified [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29300300/2348597) to make `UIScrollView` display not just another background colour but another `UIView` and `UILabel` on each page. But I could have just as easily chosen to display objects like `UITableView`, `UIButton` or `UIImage`.

Potentially, `UIScrollView` could be much more than a giant content view where users scroll from one part to the next, e.g., some pages might have a `UIButton` that takes a user to a specific page, the same way we use books.

**Code Improvements**

My question has evolved since I first posted it. Initially the labels piled up on page 1 (as shown *below*) but this has now been corrected. I also included [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36324142/2348597) to make the font larger.

**Further improvement ?**

As the code evolved I became more aware of other issues e.g. iPhone 5 images (*below*) appear differently on iPhone 7 where the `UILabel` is centred but not the `UIView`. So my next challenge is possibly to learn how to combine `UIScrollView` with `Autolayout.` I invite anyone to spot other things that might be wrong.

[image]
**ViewController.swift (corrected)**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {

let scrollView       = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480))

var views            = [UIView]()
var lables           = [UILabel]()

var colors:[UIColor] = [UIColor.red, UIColor.magenta, UIColor.blue, UIColor.cyan, UIColor.green, UIColor.yellow]
var frame: CGRect    = CGRect.zero
var pageControl: UIPageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 500, width: 200, height: 50))


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    initialiseViewsAndLables()
    configurePageControl()

    scrollView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    for index in 0..<colors.count {

        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        frame.size                            = self.scrollView.frame.size
        self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled       = true

        views[index].frame               = frame
        views[index].backgroundColor     = colors[Int(index)]
        views[index].layer.cornerRadius  = 20
        views[index].layer.masksToBounds = true

        lables[index].frame              = frame
        lables[index].center             = CGPoint(x: (view.frame.midX + frame.origin.x), y: view.frame.midY)
        lables[index].text               = String(index + 1)
        lables[index].defaultFont        = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: CGFloat(200))
        lables[index].textAlignment      = .center
        lables[index].textColor          = .black

        let subView1                     = views[index]
        let subView2                     = lables[index]

        self.scrollView .addSubview(subView1)
        self.scrollView .addSubview(subView2)
    }

    print(views, lables)

    self.scrollView.contentSize               = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(colors.count), height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
    pageControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("changePage:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}


func initialiseViewsAndLables() {
    // Size of views[] and lables[] is linked to available colors
    for index in 0..<colors.count {
        views.insert(UIView(), at:index)
        lables.insert(UILabel(), at: index)
    }
}

func configurePageControl() {
    // Total number of available pages is based on available colors
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages                 = colors.count
    self.pageControl.currentPage                   = 0
    self.pageControl.backgroundColor               = getColour()
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor        = UIColor.black
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.green
    self.view.addSubview(pageControl)

}

func getColour() -> UIColor {
    let index = colors[pageControl.currentPage]
    return (index)
}

func changePage(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage) * scrollView.frame.size.width, y: 0), animated: true)
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageNumber                                  = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage                         = Int(pageNumber)
    pageControl.backgroundColor                     = getColour()
    }
}
```

**Extension**

```
    extension UILabel{
    var defaultFont: UIFont? {
        get { return self.font }
        set { self.font = newValue }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because of this: lables[Int(index)].center  = CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX, y: view.frame.midY). You first set the frame, which, internally, sets center and bounds, but then you reset the center to the view center; view in question being the view property of the view controller, therefore all labels end up having the same center.

Comment: Also, views.append(UIView()) and lables.append(UILabel()) seem unnecessary as you've already added views and labels in initialiseViewsAndLables()

Comment: @Baglan, spot on! I'll accept if you can submit this as your answer. I'm also still looking for an alternative to append which involves minimal changes in initialisation of the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centre point of the lable on each frame must be offset by the origin of the content view (*as Baglan pointed out*). I've modified the following line of code accordingly.

```
lables[Int(index)].center = CGPoint(x: (view.frame.midX + frame.origin.x), y: view.frame.midY)
```