# How to change the font size globally in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to write an extension, to change `UIControl` components font size

```
extension UIViewController {

func changeFontSize(){
    for v in self.view.subviews{
        var fontSize = CGFloat(10)
        if let V = v as? UIButton       {V.titleLabel?.font = V.titleLabel?.font.withSize(fontSize)}
        if let V = v as? UILabel        {V.font = V.font.withSize(fontSize)}
        if let V = v as? UITextField    {V.font = V.font?.withSize(fontSize)}
    }
}
```

My problem is with some components like UITableView ,  how can I access the cells elements, and the UITableView Section header components so that I make the extension also change all subviews of all types texts fonts ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a recursive implementation so that you go into the subviews of any views. And your extension should be on `UIView`, not `UIViewController`.

```
extension UIView {
    func changeFontSize(){
        let fontSize = CGFloat(10)
        if let v = self as? UIButton {
            v.titleLabel?.font = v.titleLabel?.font.withSize(fontSize)
        } else if let v = self as? UILabel {
            v.font = v.font.withSize(fontSize)
        } else if let v = self as? UITextField {
            v.font = v.font?.withSize(fontSize)
        } else {
            for v in subviews {
                v.changeFontSize()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wish to call this on a view controller, simple do:

```
someViewController.view.changeFontSize()
```

Comment: I just tried this, it works great, ... thanks, and good idea for recursive style.

Answer (score 2):

Another common option is to use `UIAppearance`

And since `UIButton`s use `UILabel` as a subview, it would work there too.

```
extension UILabel {
    var defaultFont: UIFont? {
        get { return self.font }
        set { self.font = newValue }
    }
}


UILabel.appearance().defaultFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)
```

Repeat for `UITextField` and other controls.

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36324142/127422

See also [NSHipster's post on UIAppearance](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/)

Comment: when I study UIAppearance I will tell you if it does the job or not, thanks.